# Clang Power Tools VsWhere could not detect Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, clang, clangpowertools

just installed Clang Power Tools for VS 2019 Community, I go to build and it throws with the following error:

```
throw "VsWhere could not detect Visual Studio $($global:c ...

+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (VsWhere could n... Studio 2017 *.:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : VsWhere could not detect Visual Studio 2017 *.
```

Anyone else had this issue?

The requirements at the bottom of:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caphyon.ClangPowerTools

state VS 2017 / 2019.....

Answer (score 0):

Seems the extension required VS2017 build tools at a minimum.

Closing....